# Tensor contraction computation

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, contraction-operator

I am currently trying to implement tensors as multidimensional arrays in C++, which is why i am asking this with regards to algorithmic computability.

I would like to implement the contraction of two tensors **A = A<sup>abc...n</sup>** and **B = B<sub>n...xyz</sub>** and **C = AB** such that a through z represent the dimensions of **A** and **B**. **A** and **B** can have arbitrary dimension and a through z can be arbitrarily large.

It is extremely difficult to find actual sources on this, without having to first take a few online courses about this topic. If you have some sources regarding this topic, i would greatly appreciate it.

EDIT: Sort of like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbsJ6urR4x0 Which indices with which and where do they go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculating the component values of a tensor contraction simply involves pairing one contravariant (upper) index of one tensor with a covariant (lower) index of the other tensor and then summing over both indices.

So the component values of the contracted tensor $C^{abc\dots}_{\dots xyz}$ are given in terms of the component values $A^{abc \dots n}$ and $B_{n \dots xyz}$ by

$C^{abc\dots}_{\dots xyz} = \sum_{n=1}^{k}A^{abc\dots n}B_{n\dots xyz}$

where $k$ is the dimension of the underlying vector space. Using the convention of the Einstein summation convention the sum operator is omitted (and understood to be implied by the repeated index label $n$) so the same expression is written as

$C^{abc\dots}_{\dots xyz} = A^{abc\dots n}B_{n\dots xyz}$

Comment: Just for clarification and ease of mind: it could theoretically be also $A^{abc...n}$ and $B_{n}$, could it not? But $A^{abc...n}$ and $B^{n...xyz}$ are not possible?!

Comment: @CleboSevic you can do the arithmetical calculation of $\sum_{n=1}^{k}A^{abc\dots n}B^{n\dots xyz}$ but what you get out of that will not be the components of a tensor. If you want the output to be the component values of a tensor then you must contract a contravariant index from one tensor with a covariant index from another.

Comment: Thank you very much ... i have been trying to understand this for weeks, and no where could an answer be found. Thanks again